# Automate moving to B repository from A repository using svnkit

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

We have two repository of subversion in our sites.

A Repository : For development.
B Repository : For build and deployment.

1. Our developers modifies files and then commit to A  Repository.
2. Our builder is move or copy  to B repository from A repository
3. Our builder build based on B repository.

I want to automate moving to B repository from A repository using svnkit.

Please kindly help me How to implement. what kind of api in svnkit do we use?

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious: what problem is it you're trying to solve by moving commit data between repos?

Comment: For moving file to B repository, First export file from A repoistory. But I can not commit to B repository because local file that A repository was exported file, does not have .svn file.

Comment: Sure, I understand what it is you're doing, I'm just curious as to why you're doing. For what reason do you need to ship data between repos? There might be a better solution to your problem.

Comment: currently, After Our developer modifed file that syncronized with A repository using eclipse svn plugin, write file on modified file list (xlsx). builder move to B repository on file, one by one based on modified file list(xlsx).   I want to automate above handwork.

Comment: I have implemented application that exports file based on modified list (xlsx).

Comment: I need to way that local files that don't have .svn file commit to B repository file.